# How to increment formula by column (A3-A2, B3-B2, C3-C2 and so on)

Tags: excel

I have a column in a table that needs to be populated from data in another table.

For example,

```
D1 = A3-A2
E1 = B3-B2
F1 = C3-C2
```

and so on.

Basically, I am unsure how to increment the subtraction by columns, and then drag it down along another column.

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details on how your sheet looks like along with desired output.

Comment: See photo and my workbook here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzg7bDcyZobbNkR3R0x3ajdnMlk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Cell A6` enter the following formula and drag/copy it down.

```
=INDEX($3:$3, ROW()-4)-INDEX($2:$2, ROW()-4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  One question, what does 'Row()-4' refer to?

Comment: @Nick - `ROW()` will returns the current row number. So `ROW() - 4` will subtract 4 from current row, e.g. if you are on row 6, then `ROW() - 4` will give `6-4` i.e. `2`. For details see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d).

Answer (score 1):

@Mrig's answer is perfectly correct. Just another way to do it would be to put in the formula:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,0,ROW(A1))-OFFSET($A$3,0,ROW(A1))
```

Hope this helps.